# Java: "illegal start of expression" en Jupyter Notebook con VS Code

Tags: java, vscode, jupyter

Al hacer "Hola Mundo" en Java retorna el error "illegal start of expression" después de package. Uso Jupyter Notebook con el kernel de java en la versión Code-Insiders de VS Code.

Si comento la línea de package, aparece que está bien pero no imprime nada. Aclaro que esto solo me pasa en el Jupyter notebook dentro de VS Code, pues al correr el mismo código en un archivo Hola_Mundo.java en VS Code lo corre sin problemas. A prueba y error tuve que comentar el paquete, la clase y el main para que imprimiera en notebook, pero no se a qué se debe esto y si tendré que hacerlo siempre o es un error del notebook.

Aquí dejo el código. Les agradezco su ayuda y pido de antemano disculpas si es una pregunta elemental, pero soy nuevo en desarrollo y no he encontrado la solución en los hilos con el mismo error.

```
package semana1;

public class Hola_Mundo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hola, Mundo!");
    }
}
```

```
|   package semana1;
illegal start of expression
```

Comment: El código parece correcto, ¿estás seguro de que no tienes nada antes del código?

Comment: Hola @SJuan76, así es. Incluso lo he hecho en un nuevo archivo llamado prueba1.ipynb y me da el mismo error y de nuevo solo imprime cuando comento dichas líneas.

Comment: ¿qué es un archivo ipynb? El código fuente de una clase java ha de estar en un archivo .java, en concreto este ha de estar en una archivo `Hola_Mundo.java` en la carpeta `semana1`.

Comment: Todos los archivos de Jupyter Notebook tienen esta extensión .ipynb sin importar si se trabaja en Python, en Java o en otros lenguajes ya que en teoría solo hay que cambiar el kernel en cada caso (Es lo que tengo entendido). También lo he hecho como tu dices, con el archivo `Hola_Mundo.java` en la carpeta `semana1` (en VS Code) y corriendo desde ese archivo no hay problema, el problema es cuando lo hago desde el .ipynb (en VS Code) y quiero continuar allí porque el Notebook se me facilita para aprender ya que me permite agregar imágenes y texto con formato, exportar en diapositivas etc.